# rotate labels of mosaicplot

Tags: r

Would anyone happen to know how to rotate the labels in a mosaicplot - see for example this code:

```
employee <- read.csv("Products.csv", TRUE, sep = ",",
                     na.strings = TRUE)

count <- table(employee$EnglishCountryRegionName, 
               employee$Color)
count
mosaicplot(count)
```

taken from [here](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/mosaic-plot-in-r/). Using ggplot I would usually use:

```
theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=45, vjust=0.5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with `las` parameter, but it has only 4 options (see `help("par")`):

```
count <- table(mtcars$cyl, 
               mtcars$gear)
dimnames(count)[[1]] <- c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")
dimnames(count)[[2]] <- c("ddd", "eee", "fff")
count
#     ddd eee fff
# aaa   1   8   2
# bbb   2   4   1
# ccc  12   0   2

mosaicplot(count, las=2)
```